# Vue - после перехода по прямой ссылки не срабатывает хук mounted в компоненте

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Использую `VueRouter`.
Если перехожу с домашней страницы, все пашет как надо. Но если зайти по прямой ссылке, то в компоненте `MalfuncContent` не срабатывают хуки, ни какие...

```
const routes = [
{
     path: '',
     name: 'home',
     component: DefaultHome,
},
{
    path:'/malfunc/:id/',
    name: 'malfunc',
    component: MalfuncContent,
},
]
App.vue
<template>
   <v-app>
     <TopPanelInfo/>
     <router-view></router-view>
     <Reviews/>
     <ContactForm/>
     <Map/>
     <Footer/>
   </v-app>

</template>

<script>
import TopPanelInfo from './components/TopPanelInfo';
import Reviews from './components/Reviews';
import Map from './components/MapYandex';
import ContactForm from './components/ContactForm';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    TopPanelInfo,
    Reviews,
    ContactForm,
    Map,
    Footer,
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Можно код где подключаете компоненты?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился правильным подключением компонента

```
component: () => import('../components/MalfuncContent')
```